# How can I provide facebook and google login in Symfony3?

Tags: symfony

I am using FOSUserBundle for user's login and registration. But how can I implement it?

I have tried HWIOAuthBundle but it supports Symfony2 onlye.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

A good guide that always helped me out was the Docs:
[Getting Started With FOSUserBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html)

After you did this everything should be set up.

When you type in

```
$ php bin/console debug:router
```

you should see:

```
 fos_user_security_login             GET|POST   ANY      ANY    /login                     
 fos_user_security_check             POST       ANY      ANY    /login_check               
 fos_user_security_logout            GET        ANY      ANY    /logout                    
 fos_user_profile_show               GET        ANY      ANY    /profile/    
 ........
```

If you go to the page /login you should already see the login form.

Also a good guide for the first start is :[Course: FOSUserBundle FTW! Tutorial](https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/fosuserbundle-ftw)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But can you tell me how can I provide social login with fosuserbundle in Symfony3?

Comment: I just started with symfony as well, didn't try to implement this yet